Why does M-x and C-x b get stuck?
Recently, I experience that M-x and C-x b gets stuck, meaning I can't move up or down in the list; only the middle item is highlighted
This is both M-x (counsel-M-x) and C-x b (ivy-switch-buffer)
This happens only in emacsclient, it seems. Is there maybe any way to reload it?
It all works fine if I just restart Emacs.
EDIT: It works fine if I exit emacs client and restart it
